# Is there a way to work with WebStorm remotely?

Tags: webstorm, smb, cifs

I'd like to work with Webstorm on a SMB shared folder, so that would be the project root. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, but it's not recommended. IDE is built in a such way that requires fast access to source files .. and when working directly over network you may experience lags and random short freezes (depends on project size/languages used/code style/network quality/etc etc -- for some it works fine, but some experience those negative effects). Note that you cannot access network path directly (UNC path) -- only via mounted drive/folder.

Comment: @LazyOne Probably with symlink I could mask from Webstorm that we are talking about a network drive. Thanks for the advice. I think I'll use git push instead to upload the modifications. It is more reliable. I'd like to test on the server and I dont want to use virtual machines, docker, etc. by this project.